# Difference between "infinite" and "indefinite"

Tags: etymology, vocabulary, prefixes

I have found that *infinite* means "very great in amount of degree" while *indefinite* refers to "a period of time that has no defined end." Is there a subtle, nuanced difference between these terms, or are they interchangeable?

The one difference I noticed is the prefix *de-*. In the etymology, what special function does *[de-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=de-&searchmode=none)* have here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main root of both words is a form of *finish*:

From the etymologies:

> *[finite](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=finite&allowed_in_frame=0)*:
>
> early 15c., "limited in space or time, finite," from Latin finitum,
>   past participle of finire "to limit, set bounds; come to an end" (see
>   finish (v.)). Related: Finitely; finiteness.
>
> *[infinite](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=infinite&allowed_in_frame=0)*:
>
> late 14c., "eternal, limitless," also "extremely great in number,"
>   from Old French infinit "endless, boundless," and directly from Latin
>   infinitus "unbounded, unlimited," from in- "not, opposite of" (see in-
>   (1)) + finitus "defining, definite," from finis "end" (see finish
>   (v.)). The noun meaning "that which is infinite" is from 1580s.
>
> *[indefinite](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=indefinite&allowed_in_frame=0)*:
>
> early 15c. (implied in indefinitely), from Latin indefinitus, from in-
>   "not, opposite of, without" (see in- (1)) + definitus, past participle
>   of definire (see define).

As you correctly noticed, the key to the distinction is in the prefix *de-* of definite:

> *[define](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=define&allowed_in_frame=0)*:
>
> late 14c., "to specify; to end," from Old French defenir, definir "to
>   finish, conclude, come to an end; bring to an end; define, determine
>   with precision," and directly from Latin definire "to limit,
>   determine, explain," from de- "completely" (see de-) + finire "to
>   bound, limit," from finis "boundary, end" (see finish (v.)). Related:
>   Defined; defining.
>
> [de-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=de-&allowed_in_frame=0):
>
> active word-forming element in English and in many words inherited
>   from French and Latin, from Latin de "down, down from, from, off;
>   concerning" (see de), also used as a prefix in Latin usually meaning
>   "down, off, away, from among, down from," but also "down to the
>   bottom, totally" hence "completely" (intensive or completive), which
>   is its sense in many English words. As a Latin prefix it also had the
>   function of undoing or reversing a verb's action, and hence it came to
>   be used as a pure privative -- "not, do the opposite of, undo" --
>   which is its primary function as a living prefix in English, as in
>   defrost (1895), defuse (1943), etc.

*Infinite* means without boundaries: going on forever, while *indefinite* is related meaning without **established** boundaries. When something is definite, a person has "*gotten down to the bottom*" of its boundaries, but when something is  *indefinite*, it may be finite, but a person has "*not gotten down to the bottom*" of where those boundaries actually are.

*Infinite* space tells us *there is no end to the space*, but *indefinite* space simply tells us *we don't **know** the end of the space*.

Comment: wow, amazingly thankful details , so I can understand profoundly. Really thank you for your efforts! I always appreciate your efforts to help people in trouble learning English.

Answer (score 0):

A simple rigorous answer can be :
infinite number B means infinitely large and not countable such that if a is a finite number, then :
a/B=0 and a*B is another infinite number.
Indefinite number C means indefinitely large but still countable ,such as the number of air molecules in a finite box.Then a/C is very small but still greater than zero and a*C is extremely large but not infinite.